# Error Casting Realm Objects as Parcelable

Tags: android, realm, parcelable

I'm trying to send a Realm object between activities.  I've read that using parcelable is the best way to do this. I get a casting error when trying to pass it through an intent though.

Adding @Primary Key created a "Primary key not found" error so I omitted it. Any help would be much appreciated!

My Realm Object class:

```
@org.parceler.Parcel( implementations = { PersonRealmProxy.class },
value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
analyze = { Person.class })
public class Person extends RealmObject {

private String name;
private int ID;
private String last_name;
private String lots_to_write;
...//getters and setters start here
```

Passing the Realm Object from MainActivity:

```
Intent new_ticket = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AllAddedPeople.class );
            new_ticket.putExtra("copyRealm", (Parcelable) myRealm);
            startActivity(new_ticket);
```

...and receiving it in 2nd Activity:

```
public class AllAddedPeople extends AppCompatActivity {

private Realm myRealm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_all_people);

    myRealm= (Realm) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MyClass");
```

Comment: `Realm object between activities. I've read that using parcelable is the best way to do this.` I'm not sure where you read that, because the *best way* to send a **RealmObject** is to send *its primary key*, then re-query it in the other activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so your original Y part of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is that even though you speak of sending the Person object through the intent, you're actually trying to send `Realm` as is which is not a parcelable, which means it is completely valid for you to get a `ClassCastException` when you say `(Parcelable)realm` because it's not parcelable.

---

The *solution* to your **Y** problem is that you're supposed to use Parceler with an unmanaged version of the RealmObject.

```
@org.parceler.Parcel( /* removing implementations=... */
value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
analyze = { Person.class })
public class Person extends RealmObject {

    // @PrimaryKey // <-- this is obviously missing
    private int ID;

    private String name;
    private String last_name;
    private String lots_to_write;
    ...//getters and setters start here
```

Then you can do

```
Intent new_ticket = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AllAddedPeople.class );
        new_ticket.putExtra("person", Parcels.wrap(person.copyFromRealm()));
        startActivity(new_ticket);
```

Which you can receive like this

```
private Realm myRealm;
private Person person;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_all_people);

    myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    // THIS IS WRONG: myRealm = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MyClass");

    person = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("person")); // <-- unmanaged person obj.
```

---

But this is actually the **wrong** solution, the solution to your **X** problem is that you shouldn't be copying RealmObjects from the Realm, and you shouldn't make unmanaged RealmObject instance; they should be re-queried by primary key.

```
Intent new_ticket = new Intent (MainActivity.this, AllAddedPeople.class );
        new_ticket.putExtra("personId", person.getID());
        startActivity(new_ticket);
```

And

```
public class AllAddedPeople extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm myRealm;
    private Person person;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_all_people);

        myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        person = myRealm.where(Person.class)
                    .equalTo("ID", getIntent().getIntExtra("personId"))
                    .findFirst(); // <-- managed RealmObject
        person.addChangeListener(...
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked a charm. Out of interest, would there be any case where parceler is recommended with Realm?

Comment: Only if you need to parcel an unmanaged object into a Bundle. For example, with databinding, if you have a "save" button when the modifications are actually complete, which is when the modified unmanaged object is actually inserted to Realm.

Answer (score 0):

Your Person class should implement the Parcelable interface then you should be ok. Please refer the official document about creating parcelable class
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent new_ticket = new Intent (MainActivity.this,AllAddedPeople.class);
            new_ticket.putExtra("copyRealm", (Parcelable) myRealm);
            startActivity(new_ticket);
```

you don't need to cast your myRealm reference to Parcelable

it should be:

```
 Intent new_ticket = new Intent (MainActivity.this,AllAddedPeople.class);
                new_ticket.putExtra("copyRealm", myRealm);
                startActivity(new_ticket);
```

and in other activity

```
private Realm myRealm;
```

should be

```
private MyClass myRealm;
```

also change

```
 myRealm= (Realm) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MyClass");
```

to

```
 myRealm= (MyClass) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("MyClass");
```